# I'm facing a TypeError in react js which says "Routes.map()" is not a function in Component.tsx:688

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

```
Navbar.js:

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Linnk } from 'react-router-dom'


export default class Navbar extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">NewsMonkey</Link>
                        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                            <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <Link className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" to="/">Home</Link>
                                </li> 

                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/business">Business</Link>
                                </li>

                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/entertainment">Entertainment</Link>
                                </li>

                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/general">General</Link>
                                </li>

                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/health">Health</Link>
                                </li>

                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/science">Science</Link>
                                </li>

                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/sports">Sports</Link>
                                </li>

                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/technology">Technology </Link>
                                </li>  

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </>
        )
    }
}


App.js: 

import './App.css';

import Navbar from './component/Navbar';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import News from './component/News';

import {
  createBrowserRouter as Router,
  RouterProvider,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <div>
        <Navbar/>
        <RouterProvider>
            {/* <Route exact path="/business" element= {<News key="business" pageSize={10} country="us" category="business"/>}/>

            <Route exact path="/entertainment" element= {<News key="entertainment" pageSize={10} country="us" category="entertainment"/>}/>

            <Route exact path="/general" element= {<News key="general" pageSize={10} country="us" category="general"/>}/>

            <Route exact path="/health" element= {<News key="health" pageSize={10} country="us" category="health"/>}/>

            <Route exact path="/science" element= {<News key="science" pageSize={10} country="us" category="science"/>}/>

            <Route exact path="/sports" element= {<News key="sports" pageSize={10} country="us" category="sports"/>}/>

            <Route exact path="/technology" element= {<News key="technology" pageSize={10} country="us" category="technology"/>}/> 
              */}
            <Route exact path="/technology" element= { <div>Home page</div>}/>  
                  
          </RouterProvider>
      </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm just learning react from a 1.5 year old youTube playlist and the coach was teaching how to use class based component by making an news website. The website was API based and was working fine before I install reac-router. After the Router navigation setup everything was gone and showing error. I'm stuck now!

Comment: I'm facing this errors : components.tsx:628 Uncaught TypeError: routes.map is not a function
  components.tsx:628 Uncaught TypeError: routes.map is not a function components.tsx:628 Uncaught TypeError: routes.map is not a function react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <createBrowserRouter> component:

Answer (score 0):

The `RouterProvider` is a newer `react-router-dom@6.4` Data api. It expects a `router` prop object created by one of the data router creators, e.g. `createBrowserRouter`. `createBrowserRouter` isn't a component itself, but takes all the routes you want to render and creates a `router` object that is to be passed to the `RouterProvider` component.

Example:

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  RouterProvider,
  Route,
  Outlet,
} from "react-router-dom";

const Layout = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
      <Route path="/business" element={<News key="business" pageSize={10} country="us" category="business" />} />
      <Route path="/entertainment" element={<News key="entertainment" pageSize={10} country="us" category="entertainment" />} />
      <Route path="/general" element={<News key="general" pageSize={10} country="us" category="general" />} />
      <Route path="/health" element={<News key="health" pageSize={10} country="us" category="health" />} />
      <Route path="/science" element={<News key="science" pageSize={10} country="us" category="science" />} />
      <Route path="/sports" element={<News key="sports" pageSize={10} country="us" category="sports" />} />
      <Route path="/technology" element={<News key="technology" pageSize={10} country="us" category="technology" />} /> 
    </Route>
  )
);

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

See [Picking a Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router) for more details.